# Why does the C++20 range library have its own namespace?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Why is `std::range::sort` (and other range-based algorithms) implemented in the `range` namespace? Why isn't it defined as an overload of `std::sort` taking a range?

Comment: My guess would be that it is to avoid making the control over overload resolution into a nightmare for the library specification and implementors.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Couldn't they use concepts to take care of that?

Comment: They'd need to go over every *existing* overload and update the conditions under which it is removed from an overload set. Concepts or not it's still ALOT of work to make sure it behaves correctly. I doubt there'd be ranges support in C++20 at all, had they gone that route.

Comment: Could it be a potentially breaking change? Allowing `std::sort(range, compare)` could change the meaning of `std::sort(begin, end)` in existing code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think so. The 2nd arguments would satisfy different concepts.

Comment: @cigien What if something is a valid comparator and a valid iterator at the same time? :P That's unlikely, but could be the case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hmm, you may be right. It would be a strange type indeed, but it might not break any rules :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's to avoid disrupting existing code bases. Eric Niebler, Sean Parent and Andrew Sutton discussed different approaches in their design paper [D4128](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html).

> **3.3.6 Algorithm Return Types are Changed to Accommodate Sentinels**
>
> ... In similar fashion, most algorithm get new return types when they
> are generalized to support sentinels. This is a source-breaking change
> in many cases. In some cases, like `for_each`, the change is unlikely to
> be very disruptive. In other cases it may be more so. Merely accepting
> the breakage is clearly not acceptable. We can imagine three ways to
> mitigate the problem:
>
> 1. Only change the return type when the types of the iterator and the sentinel differ. This leads to a slightly more complicated interface
>    that may confuse users. It also greatly complicates generic code,
>    which would need metaprogramming logic just to use the result of
>    calling some algorithms. For this reason, this possibility is not
>    explored here.
> 2. Make the new return type of the algorithms implicitly convertible to the old return type. Consider `copy`, which currently returns the
>    ending position of the output iterator. When changed to accommodate
>    sentinels, the return type would be changed to something like `pair<I, O>;` that is, a pair of the input and output iterators. Instead of
>    returning a `pair`, we could return a kind of pair that is implicitly
>    convertible to its second argument. This avoids breakage in some, but
>    not all, scenarios. This subterfuge is unlikely to go completely
>    unnoticed.
> 3. Deliver the new standard library in a separate namespace that users must opt into. In that case, no code is broken until the user
>    explicitly ports their code. The user would have to accommodate the
>    changed return types then. An automated upgrade tool similar to clang
>    modernize can greatly help here.
>
> We, the authors, prefer (3).

Ultimately, it was to be the least disruptive to existing code bases that move onto building using C++20 enabled compilers. It's the approach they themselves preferred, and seems like the rest is history.

Comment: I didn't think about the return type that would need to accommodate both the old and new code. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: What, no love for `rfor_each` `rtransform`?  Why use a namespace when you can prefix everything with some stupid extra characters?  (I kid)

Comment: rrbegin() sounds great ^^