# Is it ok to do namespace ranges = std::ranges;

Tags: c++, c++20

Since C++20, it seems that std::ranges:: is capable of almost everything std:: can do (looking at range algorithms).

Is it a good practice to just write `namespace ranges = std::ranges;` in the topmost header of one's project ?

For example, a namespace alias is already done for views:

```
namespace std {
    namespace views = ranges::views;
}
```

EDIT @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica: one single question

Comment: Please only ask one question per-question. #3 is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64518019/817643).  #2 is because **all** the C++ standard library is in namespace std. The only exceptions are C legacy and macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't want to pollute the global space with a second namespace.

1. When developing a library, you can do this inside your MyLib namespace so that there is no pollution => it is convenient because you can simply use ranges:: inside the MyLib scope, whatever the header or the source file.
2. When developing a simple project, you can do this in a "define.hpp" file because it is up to you to decide what ranges:: means (the standard protects your right to alias it or not following if you already have a ranges class for example).

So yes, it is OK as long as you don't pollute one's people global scope with your API.